# Record's landing page not displaying using GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork, xsl

I'm working on customizing our GeoNetwork metadata schema which is mostly based on `dublin-core` schema. Each record should have a landing page which is accessible under `{portal-address}/resources/records/{metdataUuid}` and it should look like this:

[image]

This works fine with `dublin-core` schema, but with our schema the page is not rendering and it's showing an empty page.

Which xsl files in the schema are used to generate this page display which is loaded with the endpoint `{portal-address}/resources/records/{metdataUuid}`?

I couldn't identify which xsl sheet is responsible for the error.